# create an edit function for each object of array

Tags: javascript

I have create edit function for each of the object of array.

```
arr=[{
    EmpCode: 'A102',
    Name: 'James'         
   }, {
      EmpCode:'A106', 
      Name:'Mary' 
      },  {
       EmpCode:'A112',
        Name:'Bob'          
      }];

     var len=arr.length; 
      for(var i=0;i<len;i++)
 {  

    var obj=arr[i];

    var empcode="<div class='all' id='id1'>"+obj.EmpCode+"</div>";
    var name="<div class='all'  id='id2'>"+obj.Name+"</div>";       
    var Edit="<button class='all'  id='id8' onclick='edit()'>"+"Edit"+"</button>";  

    var row="<div>"+empcode+name+Edit+"</div>"; 
    var element=document.createElement('div');
    element.innerHTML=row;
    document.body.appendChild(element);

    }
```

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: i have to create edit function for all objects of  array

Comment: Then you want to put something in the `edit()` function you're using in the buttons, and you'd be best off passing in the `EmpCode` with each iteration. On another note, I'd recommend you read up about best practices for laying out code, clean code is a lot easier to read and make sense of, and running this code will generate bad HTML, element IDs need to be unique, with this you'll have multiple `id1 id2 id8`.

Comment: ok thank you so much

Comment: If the below answer solved your question please accept it as the answer, if not, please comment as to what isn't working with it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Comment text:
Then you want to put something in the `edit()` function you're using in the buttons, and you'd be best off passing in the `EmpCode` with each iteration. On another note, I'd recommend you read up about best practices for laying out code, clean code is a lot easier to read and make sense of, and running this code will generate bad HTML, element IDs need to be unique, with this you'll have multiple `id1 id2 id8`.

The below line slight change:

```
var Edit = "<button class='all' id='id8' onclick='edit(" + obj.EmpCode + ")'>"+"Edit"+"</button>";
```

Then you want to add a function like...

```
function edit(empCode) {
    if (empCode === undefined) {
        return;
    }
    // Your edit code goes here, you can now use the variable empCode
}
```